# Cauchy integral theorem - residue calculus

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Let $C(0;2)$ denote the circle of radius $2$ centred at the origin, traversed once in the positive direction. Evaluate $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0;2)}\frac{e^{z^2}}{(z+i)^2}$$

Attempt: There is a double pole contained within $C(0;2)$, namely $z=-i$. We know that if $f$ is a meromorphic function and a pole of $f$ is of order $k$ then $$res(f,z_0)=lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}\big[(z-z_0)^kf(z)\big]$$ In our case we have $k=2$, and so $res(f,-i)=\lim_{z\rightarrow -i}\frac{d}{dz}(z+i)^2\frac{e^{z^2}}{(z+i)^2}=\lim_{z\rightarrow -i}\frac{d}{dz}e^{z^2}=\lim_{z\rightarrow -i}2ze^{z^2}=-\frac{2i}{e}$.
Cauchy's integral formula says $$\oint _{C(0;2)}f(z)dz=2\pi i\times res(f,z_0)$$ and so $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C(0;2)}f(z)=-\frac{2i}{e}$.

My concern is that the answer is negative, although the traversion was in a positive direction. Moreover, notwithstanding this concern, I am not entirely convinced my solution should have been so long! Any comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: You got the right values. I don't understand what you mean when you say that the answer is negative.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos as in the answer is less than zero; intuitively one would expect the integral to have a value larger than zero if oriented positively

Comment: There is no natural order relation in $\Bbb C$. So, $-\frac{2i}e$ is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: $-{2i\over e}={2\over ie}$ and the artificial  problem dissappears.